# Getting the probability of a sample being between two values

Tags: r, probability, sample, population

I am learning on probabilities in populations and samples now but I'm stuck on this question.

> Suppose we have a sample with n=35 of a population with a mean of 80
>   and standard deviation of 5.
>
> What's the chance of the sample mean being between 79 and 82.

The only formula I got to solve this is this:

[image]

In which `gekend` means that it is known and `niet gekend` unknown. So I suppose I should use the formula in the second row first column. Which I can't because I don't know S2.

I have searched everywhere but I can't figure it out maybe I am wording it wrong while searching for it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think you should use the formula in the first row first column, $\sigma^2$ is known in this case (the square of the population standard deviation, e.g. $\sigma^2=25$). By using the given formula and a probability density table you can calculate $P(79 \leq \bar{X} \leq 82)$...

Comment: I looked up a tutorial which uses `σ/sqrt(n)`  which gives me `0.8451542547285166` which seems to be the right answer to me, but I can't find a way to get the same answer with that formula. Is it really possible with that?

Comment: I finally managed to find it apparently for the standard error I just need to get the square root of `σ2/n`

Comment: I'm getting 19% after the probability table for P(79≤X¯≤82) is that right?

Comment: I mean 81% I think it calculated wrong because I used a negative

Comment: Yes indeed, I think 81% is the right answer.